# Availability of inputs to reducers

Tags: mapreduce

In the Map-Reduce stages, it enforces a barrier between the map and reduce. Reducers cannot continue until all the mappers completed their assigned jobs. Is it possible for a reducer to start a new job earlier for higher efficiency? If the answer is yes or no then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the reduce phase can’t complete until all the mappers have completed their assigned workload. Because it can’t be predicted ahead of time because the prediction of completing jobs and which reduce which job is totally unpredictable till the time all mappers are finished.